# Compute the Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

I'm fairly sure I have solved it correctly, but certainty in these matters is most appreciated. $\int_{-1}^{1} e^{x}d(4g(x)),$ where $g(x)=-1_{[-1,0]}(x) + 3\cdot_{(0,1]}(x) = [e^{0}][4 \cdot 3 - 4 \cdot (-1)]=16$

Comment: What you wrote doesn't seem right, $g(x)$ does not equal $16$ anywhere. I'm assuming you meant, that the integral is $16$. Perhaps you should rewrite what you meant more clearly.

Comment: You are correct. I meant to define g(x) as I have above. However, given how g(x) is defined for the integral, I meant to say that it is indeed equal to 16. I will adjust when I have sufficient time. Thank you pointing out how what I wrote could be misleading.